# How to display netrw's current path? The default banner is to stuffed

Tags: netrw

I use the following settings to hide the netrw banner:

```
let g:netrw_banner=0
```

I know that this also displays the current directory, but it also displays a bunch of other things I'm not interested in. I just want to see the current place I'm in while using netrw.

Is there an option to reconfigure the banner? Or other alternative to display only the path I'm in netrw?

Comment: What is "a bunch of other things"?

Comment: This is how the netrw banner looks: http://imgur.com/a/HlDhc . I want to see only the path(in this example it's "/home"). Does this clarify your question?

Comment: It does, you can add this your question I think.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you have:

> let g:netrw_banner=0

You can use 'I', 'i', 'qf' :

- **I** - Toggle the banner (in order to see the path).     (*:h netrw-I*)
- **i** - "The "i" map cycles between the thin, long, wide, and tree listing formats...", "The tree listing format has a top directory followed by files and directories preceded by one or more "|"s, which indicate the directory depth.  One may open and close directories by pressing the  key while atop the directoryname. |     (*h: netrw-i*)
- **qf** - will show information about the file or directory (and also the path). | (*:h netrw-qf*)

Comment: Didn't knew about qf, thanks for the tip. It seems to me that currently netrw has no way of configuring the banner to display only the current directory.

Comment: Me neither, I just found out about it thanks to your question. Thank you!
Remember that you can still quickly (un)toogle the banner with 'I', it doesn't matter if you have 'banner=0'. I looked in the plugin files, and the banner seems to be just a couple of called functions. In theory, you could delete what you don't need and stay only with the banner. But it is up to you how deep you wanna go... Thanks again for asking, I learned a lot. ( :